# Is it possible to create a hierarchical multi-project build with sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I know this had been asked before but all these questions were either deleted or don't have satisfactory answers, so I ask it again:

In an SBT build, is it possible to arrange and define the subprojects in a hierarchical way? e.g.:

```
root
  foo
    foofoo
    foobar
  bar
    barfoo
    barbar
```

where each project has its own `build.sbt` but inherits settings from its top-level (aggregator) project (so `foofoo` and `foobar` inherit settings from `foo` and `foo` inherits settings from `root`)?

Maven has this possibility, but cross-building is quite painful with this one so I want to use SBT.

If it can be done, how is it done?

Comment: What have you already tried before asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by configuring **build.sbt** of your `root project`. The **build.sbt** would look something like below in your case:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala) //assuming its a play scala project

lazy val foo = project.in(file("<path-to-foo-project>")).dependsOn(root)

lazy val bar = project.in(file("<path-to-bar-project>")).dependsOn(root)

lazy val foofoo = project.in(file("<path-to-foofoo-project>")).dependsOn(foo)

lazy val foobar = project.in(file("<path-to-foobar-project>")).dependsOn(foo)

lazy val barfoo = project.in(file("<path-to-barfoo-project>")).dependsOn(bar)

lazy val barbar = project.in(file("<path-to-barbar-project>")).dependsOn(bar)
```

Comment: This is not what I want. I already got this approach to work. I want to keep the individual `build.sbt` files small, so I want one `build.sbt` with all common settings, one `build.sbt` for `foo` containing `foo`-specific settings and for each project, an individual `build.sbt` for their individual settings.

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer because it indeed seems the only possibility. I am now helping myself by defining regions and using folding to minimize at least visible clutter.

Answer (score 0):

refer to this: https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html#Default+root+project

you can define multiple sbt files under sub-dirs and use root sbt to include them. they will be auto-merged into one big sbt to be run.

> Any .sbt files in foo, say foo/build.sbt, will be merged with the
>   build definition for the entire build, but scoped to the hello-foo
>   project.